# Netflix very quiet on Mac OS

Tags: macos, audio, netflix

Possibly a very simply problem  but I'm not as familiar with OSX as I am with Windows or Linux.

When I watch anything on Netflix on OSX (10.7.2) which uses Silverlight (5.0.61118.0) whether I use external speakers or internal speakers, the volume is frustratingly low.

To make a film watchable, I have to move the system volume slider to the top, and on my external speakers (which are amplified) I have to turn the volume dial to 80% or even higher on some titles.

Suffice to say, any sound notification alerts that come through literally scare the living daylights out of me and have woken my child/wife at times!

I've seen various things on the App Store that purport to amplify certain sounds, but I can't bring myself to pay for something that seems so obviously missing from the sound driver set.

Am I missing a mixer/EQ preference or do I need to go poking around elsewhere ?
As well as alert notifications, iTunes/VOX/VLC all have correct volumes.

Please help!

Edit:

This is the kind of Mac:

```
  Model Name:   iMac
  Model Identifier: iMac9,1
  Processor Name:   Intel Core 2 Duo
  Processor Speed:  2.93 GHz
  Number of Processors: 1
  Total Number of Cores:    2
  L2 Cache: 6 MB
  Memory:   4 GB
```

Basically, 2009 24" iMac using the built-in Intel High-Definition audio.

Comment: What model Mac? Get the exact model property like "MacPro1,1".

Comment: Good point, I've added that to the bottom of my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only volume levels on Macs are the one at the top on the menubar, and the one within the browser, as part of Netflix.

Comment: Disappointing but thanks anyway; I don't have the reputation required to vote you up, sorry.

Comment: No worries. I would suggest external speakers to help push that level higher.

Comment: You can install a Chome extension called Volume boost if you're watching something on Netflix or youtube (or whatever inside Google Chrome). If you have something downloaded, then you can boost volume using VLC player.

Answer (score 0):

Turn up the Mac volume using F12 and then on Netflix, turn up the volume using the sound icon in the bottom bar (works the same as the YouTube sound bar).

Comment: Wow! How did you manage to bring such a deep and profound answer to our attention?